# Coordinating conjunctions between different pairs that are close to each other

Tags: conjunctions, repetition, coordinating-conjunctions

I'd like to write a sentence with the following "logical structure":

```
                        I
                        ' 
                       can 
            ,-----------'-------------,
          play                      speak
   ,-------'------,                   ,
the piano     the guitar           Russian
```

and I need to convey the three bits of information in this particular order (`can-play-piano`, `can-play-guitar`, `can-speak-Russian`).

Which of those options would be grammatical?

1. I can play the piano, the guitar and speak Russian
2. I can play the piano and the guitar and speak Russian

The first version avoids the repeated "and", but it also lacks a coordinating conjunction between the two elements under "play", that are now only separated by a comma. Conversely, the second version correctly marks each pair of equal syntactical value (piano-guitar; play-speak) with a conjunction, but it has two "and" in a row which may be perceived as heavy writing.

(I know the sentence could be rephrased, but please focus on the two options I gave: do they both sound good? or bad? or does just one?)

Comment: Personally I would either use two sentences giving "I can play the piano and the guitar. I can also speak Russian" or I would invert the sentence so that the single language skill comes first so you get "I can speak Russian, I can also play the piano and the guitar". Doing either of these separates the two, unrelated, sets of skills in a way that ordering them the other way in one sentence does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. suggests that {I can play} *the piano*, *the guitar*, *speak Russian*. It is as if *speak Russian* were a noun phrase, the object of *play*. This makes no sense.
2. {I} *can play the piano and the guitar* is one concept saying what {I} can do. The added concept that {I} *can speak Russian* is a second concept of equal status, so needs to be separated by a comma: *{I} can play the piano and the guitar, and speak Russian*

The second version is therefore acceptable with the addition of the comma.

I have used {} to indicate the common links to the italicized concepts. Apologies if this seems a little awkward.